# Emulator launching Error

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am the beginner to the android, I done some application in android and successfully run them.
I wrote the application, now the problem is ,whenever I run the project ,in console window it shows the error message like:

```
[2011-01-04 22:00:47 - Emulator] unknown option: -sdcardC:\Android\sdcard
[2011-01-04 22:00:47 - Emulator] please use -help for a list of valid options".
```

help me to fix this problem.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    try{
        rl= new URL("http://www.androidbook.com/akc/filestorage/android/documentfiles/3389/movie.mp4");
        File file = new File("movie.mp4");
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what information you have provided

```
[2011-01-04 22:00:47 - Emulator] unknown option: -sdcardC:\Android\sdcard
```

There should be a space between the `-sdcard` option and the path to the file.

The syntax is `>emulator.exe -sdcard <file>`

This is how the `-help` option describes the syntax of the `-sdcard` option

```
-sdcard <file>                 SD card image (default <system>/sdcard.img
```

This will solve the problem

```
>emulator.exe -sdcard C:\Android\sdcard
```